# Flutter IOS dependencies version issues

Tags: ios, flutter

I am trying to build a Flutter IOS project which was working fine before few months. Today when I upgraded Flutter and all the project dependencies, I am not able to build my IOS project.

I tried everything, like removing the Podfile and Podfile.lock files, pod upgrade, dependencies, flutter clean, etc.

Whenever I run pod install, it gives me the following error.

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GTMSessionFetcher/Core":
In Podfile:
firebase_storage (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_storage/ios`) was resolved to 11.1.0, which depends on
  Firebase/Storage (= 10.7.0) was resolved to 10.7.0, which depends on
    FirebaseStorage (~> 10.7.0) was resolved to 10.7.0, which depends on
      GTMSessionFetcher/Core (< 4.0, >= 2.1)

google_mlkit_text_recognition (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_mlkit_text_recognition/ios`) was resolved to 0.5.0, which depends on
  GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition (~> 3.2.0) was resolved to 3.2.0, which depends on
    MLKitTextRecognition (~> 1.4.0-beta6) was resolved to 1.4.0-beta6, which depends on
      MLKitCommon (~> 8.0) was resolved to 8.0.0, which depends on
        GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 1.1)

 CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "MLKitVision":
In Podfile:
google_mlkit_commons (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_mlkit_commons/ios`) was resolved to 0.2.0, which depends on
  MLKitVision

google_mlkit_text_recognition (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_mlkit_text_recognition/ios`) was resolved to 0.5.0, which depends on
  GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition (~> 3.2.0) was resolved to 3.2.0, which depends on
    MLKitTextRecognition (~> 1.4.0-beta6) was resolved to 1.4.0-beta6, which depends on
      MLKitVision (~> 4.2)
```

Thank you for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your pod file:

```
pod 'GTMSessionFetcher/Core', '~> 2.1'
```

inside your

```
target 'Runner' do
...
end
```

Comment: Hi, I added the line you suggested but still gettin the same error.

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  pod 'GTMSessionFetcher/Core', '~> 2.1'
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end